# Type.GetType returns null

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I'm trying to develop a PRISM application using WPF & Unity. Now I got to the part where I have to load my Modules in my ShellView. I try to accomplish this by using the Type.GetType method but after debugging it said null. Now I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. The only thing I know is that my ModuleType is probably not an Assembly Qualified name. Can someone help me out ?

```
 public partial class Shell : Window
{
    private IModuleManager ModuleManager;
    private IUnityContainer Container;
    private IModuleCatalog ModuleCatalog;

    public Shell(IModuleManager moduleManager, IUnityContainer container, IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
    {
        this.ModuleCatalog = moduleCatalog;

        if (moduleManager == null) throw new ArgumentException("Modulemanager is null");

        ModuleManager = moduleManager;
        ModuleManager.Run();


        Container = container;

        foreach (var module in ModuleCatalog.Modules)
        {
            OpenMainView(module);
        }

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenMainView(ModuleInfo module)
    {
        Type ModuleType = Type.GetType(module.ModuleType); //this returns null
    }
```

Comment: Is `ModuleType` instantiated?

Comment: Yes it is instantiated

Comment: @NicolasPierre I saw that you found the right answer and thus I deleted mine (because of referring to a generic problem, more than to this specific one). In any case, I understand that you used .GetType(). If your original code was wrong, you should update it for future viewers; if it was right I would love to know about it (would help me to get a good initial grasp of Prism).

Comment: I'll edit the code when i'm home from work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a stretch, but have you marked your modules with the [IModuleExport Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.mefextensions.modularity.imoduleexport%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) using the [ModuleExportAttibute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.mefextensions.modularity.moduleexportattribute%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)?

```
[ModuleExport("TestModule", typeof(TestModule), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand)]
public class MainMenuControlModule : IModule
```

**Edit:** The final problem was not that the code was not told to load the modules from disk.

Comment: I'm using a DirectoryModulecatalog so is the export tag needed ?

Comment: That is a good question. I took a peak inside the PRISM source code and it doesn't appear that the DirectoryModuleCatalog needs a module export. In the code base I use, I manually load the modules I need, so sadly I'm not experienced with the methodology that is used here. However, have you looked at the ShouldReturnAListOfModuleInfo example method in the DirectoryModuleCatalogFixture test class? That may give you an idea of what your doing differently than the official PRISM test code.

Comment: I'm so freaking stupid the module wasn't loaded -_- thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Its okay. It happens to all of us. :) Happy coding.